# comparing code size vs source size

Tags: memory, dll, code-generation, code-analysis, metrics

There are plenty of script/tools for counting line of code, and some to count functions size in terms of line of code.
But here I'm looking to a way to measure function size in terms of bytes of generated code.

Does anyone know a way/tools to extract this information from a .lib or a .dll?

For example, I know how to list function name from a .lib or .dll, and their start address, but I haven't found a way yet to get their memory footprint.

PS : I'm look for a solution on windows platform, but any answer on an alternative system is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's quite what you're after, but you could try parsing the map file as per [this tutorial](http://home.hiwaay.net/~georgech/WhitePapers/MapFiles/MapFiles.htm).

Also, if you're after a paid-for solution, the [ANTS profiler from Red-gate](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm) is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, the `size` command gives you information about that:

```
Black JL: size /usr/lib/libc.so.1
909301 + 32017 + 6731 = 948049
Black JL: size ~/lib/libjl.a
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[affbak.o]: 4849 + 44 + 4 = 4897
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[affstd.o]: 5488 + 48 + 4 = 5540
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[base64.o]: 8772 + 9 + 320 = 9101
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[basedigit.o]: 841 + 0 + 0 = 841
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[basename.o]: 996 + 0 + 0 = 996
/work1/jleffler/lib/libjl.a[bitmap.o]: 3876 + 8 + 4096 = 7980
...lots of entries omitted...
Black JL: size ~/bin/sqlcmd.64
169694 + 17728 + 8280 = 195702
Black JL: size cc3e_*.o | so
cc3e_fixed_from_gregorian.o: 1906 + 0 + 0 = 1906
cc3e_gregorian_date.o: 684 + 0 + 0 = 684
cc3e_gregorian_epoch.o: 707 + 0 + 0 = 707
cc3e_gregorian_from_fixed.o: 1729 + 0 + 0 = 1729
cc3e_gregorian_year_from_fixed.o: 1625 + 0 + 0 = 1625
cc3e_last_kday.o: 742 + 0 + 0 = 742
cc3e_nth_kday.o: 1123 + 0 + 0 = 1123
Black JL:
```

Semi-random files from around my system - which is Sun SPARC running Solaris 10, using `size` from `/usr/ccs/bin` (not the GNU version, but it is likely to give similar info).

GNU `size` under Cygwin says:

```
$ size libjl.a
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 800      64      16     880     370 affbak.o (ex libjl.a)
1008      64      16    1088     440 affstd.o (ex libjl.a)
 176       0       0     176      b0 basedigit.o (ex libjl.a)
 208       0       0     208      d0 basename.o (ex libjl.a)
 544     320    4096    4960    1360 bitmap.o (ex libjl.a)
 816       0      16     832     340 block.o (ex libjl.a)
```

However, that may not help much - when run on a DLL (C:\WINDOWS\twain.dll), GNU `size` says it doesn't recognize the file type.  OTOH, it does seem to understand '.lib' files:

```
jleffler@IBM-027DF09B37F /cygdrive/c/notes/jvm/bin
$ size jawt.lib
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     63      30       0      93      5d jawt.dll (ex jawt.lib)
     63      20       0      83      53 jawt.dll (ex jawt.lib)
     63       8       0      71      47 jawt.dll (ex jawt.lib)
      8      26       0      34      22 jawt.dll (ex jawt.lib)

jleffler@IBM-027DF09B37F /cygdrive/c/notes/jvm/bin
$ ls -l jawt.lib
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 jleffler None 1692 Oct 25  2007 jawt.lib
```